# I am trying to retrieve data of last month from table called test and date field called date what is the correct SQL syntax

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, web

> Error 1582 - Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'DATEDIFF'

I searched a lot but didn't find any working syntax of SQL - any help will be highly appreciated. I typed following syntax but it didn't work

```
select * 
from test 
where date >= DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()) - 1, 0)
  and date < DATEADD(mm,DATEDIFF(mm, 0, GETDATE()), 0)
```

Comment: this syntax is for sql-server , mysql expects two parametrs in DATEDIFF

Comment: actually i am using this coding for a web site written in php

Comment: please can anyone give a complete syntex to show all entry of last month

Comment: Yes, but you still need to follow a specific sql syntax.. you cant just write it in sql-server syntax and expect it to work ok - as it was suggested , use proper mysql syntax - datediff with two parametrs, and change dateadd to date_add

Comment: what is your date format?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL date difference expects two parameters only.

```
DATEDIFF(date1,date2)
```

Also, its `DATE_ADD` not `DATEADD` for MySQL

Source:
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp
http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
select *
from    test 
where   (year(curdate()) =  year(date)
    and month(curdate()) -1  =     month(date]) and month(curdate()) <> 1)
    or  (year(curdate()) -1 =  year(date)
    and month(date]) = 12)
```

Comment: sir how can i modify this query to view result of custom months like result of last 6 months or 1 year?

Comment: Just see my answer i think its simplier and you can modified it as you like with only changin one number

Comment: SELECT * FROM test
WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH)   ---> Six month interval   SELECT * FROM test
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 year)  --->   1 year interval

Comment: @AmbareeshSurendran Sir the above coding SELECT * FROM test WHERE MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 6 MONTH shows the entry of only the last 6th month is there any query to show all entries from last 6th month to the present date ?

Thanks in advance sir

Comment: @BabaUdayNath u can use (>=) operator instead of (=) operator

Answer (score 0):

Dont know what is your date format but If u need last month ( that means if its 3rd februaray , you need all January) you can try this:

```
SELECT * FROM test
WHERE YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)
```